# How many morphemes in 'during'?

Tags: linguistics, morphology, cranberry-morphemes

Is 'during' one morpheme or is it something like DURATION+ continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article [here](http://www.csun.edu/~sk36711/WWW2/engl302/morph.htm) that seems to be particularly relevant:

> A variety of historical developments in meaning can obscure our perceptions of morphemic status. Often the only way to recognise the presence of some morphemes is through the study of the history of the English language and of foreign languages from which English has borrowed vocabulary (primarily Latin, Greek, and French). A good dictionary which gives the **etymology** (or origin) of words can help. However, when analysing morphemes in present-day English, it is important to consider whether the morphemes of the past are still recognisable today. The word *daisy* is probably only recognisable as one morpheme by most people today, but it was once three. Your dictionary will reveal that the word comes from *day's eye*.

Now, looking at the etymology, it is easy to see the origin of the word ("during" *is* related to "duration", but was not directly formed from it):

> Late Middle English: present participle of the obsolete verb dure ‘last, endure, extend’, via Old French from Latin durare ‘to last’ (see duration).
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/during)</sub>

It seems like we should consider "during" to be two morphemes, although the first morpheme could be considered to be a [cranberry morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme).

Comment: The extract from the CSUN article 'The word daisy is probably only recognisable as one morpheme by most people today, but it was once three.' doesn't address the question "How many morphemes does a linguist in 2018 ascribe to 'daisy'?"